# return object literal showing nan

Tags: javascript, module

```
var myModule = (function(){
    var myObj = {
        fname:"Shashank",
        lname:"madan",  
        job:"Student",
        birthYear: 1999,
    }
    return {
        age:function(birthYear){
            return birthYear - 2017;
        },
        findJob:function(job){
            if(job == "Student"){
                console.log("Work Hard");
            }else{
                console.log("What do you do?");
            }
        },
        fullName: function(fname, lname){
            return this.fname + this.lname
        }   
    };
})();
```

The problem is that whenever I try to access the returned elements which are public I am getting weird results as `myModule.age()` is `NaN` and `findJob()` is `"what do you do?"` instead of `"Work Hard"`.

Comment: How do you call both methods?

Comment: If you aren't passing anything to `age`, then `birthYear` will default to `undefined`, and `undefined - 2017 = NaN`

Comment: I have written a full answer that I hope will help you understand the problem and its solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fixing your problem:

All three functions returned take in at least one argument. You haven't given them the argument they needed to return a result. That explains the `NaN` when calling `age()` and `"what do you do?"` when calling `findJob()` (essentially `job` isn't equal to "student" because it's `undefined`).

Now looking at your code I am pretty sure you want to use the variables contained inside `myObj` inside your functions so that if you call `myModule.age()` you will get `18`. So here's the code:

```js
var myModule = (function() {
  var myObj = {
    fname: "Shashank",
    lname: "madan",
    job: "Student",
    birthYear: 1999,
  }
  return {
    age: function(birthYear) {
      return 2017 - myObj.birthYear;
    },
    findJob: function(job) {
      if (myObj.job == "Student") {
        return "Work Hard";
      } else {
        return "What do you do?";
      }
    },
    fullName: function(fname, lname) {
      return myObj.fname + myObj.lname
    }
  };
})();

console.log(myModule.age())
console.log(myModule.findJob())
```

I gave you that code so you can see what was wrong with yours. You have to access `myObj` inside the returned object if you want to be able to access it's elements.

---

### Using classes

But in my opinion, this is not the best way to approach this. Let's say you want two objects instead of just one? You need to use classes. This way each object will have its own `fname`, `lname`, `job` and `fullName`.

```js
let Module = function(fname, lname, job, birthYear) {

  // on instantiation we define the object's properties with the given arguments
  this.fname = fname;
  this.lname = lname;
  this.job = job;
  this.birthYear = birthYear;
    
  this.age = function() {
      return 2017 - this.birthYear; // <- we use `this` to access the object's property
  };
  
  this.findJob = function() {
    if (this.job === "Student") {
      return "Work Hard";
    } else {
      return "What do you do?";
    }
  };
  
  this.fullName = function() {
    return this.fname + this.lname
  };

};

let myModule = new Module("Shashank", "madan", "Student", 1999);
console.log(myModule.age())
console.log(myModule.findJob())
```

Notice how I call the properties inside the class I use `this`. And as long as I am in the class's definition I can use `this` to access other properties and methods (methods are functions inside classes but they're similar).

However, when I'm outside I need to instantiate an object with the `new` syntax like so:

```
let myModule = new Module("Shashank", "madan", "Student", 1999)
```

Finally, you can create other modules: for example

```
let anotherModule = new Module ("Winnie", "The Pooh", "Bee Hunter", 1926)
```

And

```
anotherModule.fullName()
```

will of course return `"Winnie The Pooh"`.